# is still possible to use firebase with p5js in 2023?

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, p5.js

i'm trying to use firebase and p5js in the same project, i saw online that posts, and videos about this topic are all datated (6 or more years ago) and their methods to communicate between firebase and p5js don't work anymore (especially the daniel shiffman method),i'm trying to mix techniques online reading the simple javascript firebase documentation but i obviously find problems everywhere, if someone have advices about this topic, or could tell me if is still possible in 2023 please answer me, that's my html and p5js code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sketch</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

P5JS:

```
 var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "n",
  authDomain: "o",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "h",
  storageBucket: "a",
  messagingSenderId: "c",
  appId: "k"
};

const nino = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
console.log(nino);

const databa = firebase.getDatabase(nino);
console.log(databa);
// var ref = databa.ref("ciccio");



var a;
var b;
var c; 
var c1;
var d;
var e;
var f;
var butt;


function setup() {
  l = createCanvas(700, 700);
  a = createSlider(0, 700, 0);
  b = createSlider(0, 700, 0);
  c = createP("value1");
  c1 = createP("value2");
  d = createElement("h1", "SLAM SKETCH");
  e = createSlider(0, 360, 0);
  f = createP("value3");
  butt = createButton("mandala");
  l.position(800, 20);
  a.position(100, 80);
  b.position(100, 110);
  c.position(400, 65);
  c1.position(400, 95);
  d.position(100, 0);
  e.position(100, 140);
  f.position(400, 125);
  butt.position(100, 190);
  butt.mousePressed(silui);

}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  var angl = map(e.value(), 0, 360, 0, 2 * PI);
  push();
  translate(a.value(), b.value());
  rotate(-angl);

  stroke(0);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  ellipse(0, 0, 30, 30);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(0, 0, 10, 10);
  strokeWeight(5);
  line(0, 0, 50, 0);
  
  c.html(a.value());
  c1.html(b.value());
  f.html(e.value());
  
  pop();
}

function silui(){
  var data = {
     assx: a.value(),
     assy: b.value(),
     angl: e.value()
  }
  ref.push(data);
  print("ciao");
}
```

in the old html configuration i've tried, i recive errors at the beginning of the code, infact i couldn't visualize the nino variable, string const nino = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); now with this html configuration i can print and read the nino log, but the variable databa give me this error: Uncaught TypeError: firebase.getDatabase is not a function
at sketch.js:14:25, very explanatory, but that's the only function i've found on the documentation for using the realtime database; thanks for your help

i've said everything previously

Comment: I don't think this is related to P5 at all, so you may be constraining your search too much by including it. Sounds like you just need to connect to firebase. There's no integration between the two libraries and no reason you can't pass values from P5 handlers to firebase, or use firebase stored values in a P5 sketch, so you'll probably want to follow regular firebase docs and get connected, then whenever you want to save values from P5 sliders (or whatever), call those firebase functions from your P5 handlers. What kind of app are you trying to make?

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, i'm trying to visualize the surrounding environment of my esp32 homemade car. since esp32 has the ability to connect to firebase, i would like use It as the centre database/ comunication node between esp32 and p5js, I agree with you about the fact that i've focused too much research on linking specifically to p5js, but I also want to understand why there is so little information online about this esp32-firebase-p5js approach, is it just another idea from an inexperienced newbie?

Comment: Probably because p5 and firebase don't really need to know about each other, so by focusing super heavily on "p5 + firebase" information, you may be missing out on modern firebase tutorials that you'll need to help get you running. p5 is a rather small-ish visualization/creative coding library that isn't usually used in conjunction with firebase (but certainly can be, as well as any other database/backend).